# A way to display a general invalid status of a buffer using Vim CoC

Tags: vim

Is there any way to have something like a status bar in Vim with CoC (or just language server in general) that tells you when current buffer is static analysis-wise invalid, eg. has compilation or linting errors?
I am using Vim w/ CoC in an Angular project, and while CoC shows me errors just fine when I have the problematic line in my current view, I don't see those outside of the current scroll position.

Compare
[image]
to
[image]

I am just one line higher on the second picture and already have no indication of errors. I can jump preemptively to next issue with coc-diagnostic or just rely on compiler output but that's clearly not ideal.

So is there perhaps plugin to be used for this (preferably one which plays nicely with CoC), or is there any better way (workflow-wise) to quickly find out that current buffer is invalid?

Comment: Did you consider asking "$FANCY_STATUS_LINE_PLUGIN CoC Vim" to your favourite search engine?

Comment: I searched for a lot of search terms and never found anything. Status line seems to be the key term here, already found integration with lightline. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was unaware of the concept of configuring `statusline` in vim. Searching for it yielded nice integration options between lightline (which I am using) among others and Coc https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Statusline-integration.